# не удается получить список файлов в папке на PYTHON

Tags: python

код простой:

```
import os
os.listdir('c://ann')
```

ошибка: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c://ann'`

проверил все и латиницу, и возможные пробелы, и ставил слеши одиночные и двойные, обратные и прямые.
в чем может быть дело
писал в colab

Comment: если это windows то слеш в обратную сторону нужно вроде как

Comment: Очевидно, что путь указан неверно, сначала нужно разобраться, как питон видит путь, и на его примере сделать свой. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430372/how-do-i-get-the-full-path-of-the-current-files-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> может быть дело писал в colab

Тогда всё понятно. У `Google Colab` своя файловая система `Linux`, там нет никакого диска `C:`.
Вы можете загрузить туда свои локальные файлы, либо подключить свой раздел с `Google Drive`.
Но локальный ваш диск `Google Colab` никак увидеть не сможет.

Comment: Да спасибо
проблема в goole colab, в pycharm работает